# The Qt installer is still a good idea?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, qt-installer

On https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-getting-started.html it says

```
The supported Qt version is 5.12.7
```

But current Qt is already on 5.15 (https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-5.15.2-released)

Why Qt installer does not support current Qt?

It seems not possible to build it with Qt 5.12.4

[image]

Interestingly I managed to build version 3.0.1 with Qt 5.12.10 msvc2017_x64.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is just a left-over in the documentation. Did you tried?

Comment: some lines above on the same page they write "Currently, the tested combination for Windows is Qt 5.12.4 with MSVC 2015.". I guess thats another left-over that needs an update. I mean why would they claim that 5.12.7 is supported but only test it for 5.12.4

Comment: @AdrianMaire Yes I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67358145/errors-building-qt-installer-framework-on-windows